# Why doesn't calling disconnect function work?

Tags: javascript, mqtt, paho

I'm using the Paho MQTT client to connect to an MQTT server.
After I'm done receiving messages I run this bit of code:

```
function dummy() {
    console.log("dummy");
}

if (window.MQTTClient!==null){
    console.log("Disconnecting  from MQTT server...");
    window.MQTTClient.disconnect;
    window.MQTTClient.onMessageArrived=dummy;
    let element = document.getElementById("pahoClient");
    console.log(element);
    element.parentElement.removeChild(element);    
    window.MQTTClient=null;
}
```

The element with Id=pahoClient contains the javascript code for the Paho client.
Disconnecting and removing it should stop the onMessageArrived event from firing but it doesn't.
After the code is done running, the dummy function still gets called.
I cannot make it stop.

If I run my code again it will reload the Paho client script and receive 2 messages for each MQTT topic change. Run again: 3,4,5 and so on.

Only after refreshing the page I get rid of the extra callbacks, but I don't want that.

Background information:
The javascript code I'm talking about is running in "Wick-editor" an online Flash-clone that runs Javascript.
I'm connecting to the public MQTT test-server at: mqtt.eclipseprojects.io

Answer (score 2):

The line containing `window.MQTTClient.disconnect;` will not do anything. To [call a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#calling_functions) you need to provide a parameter list (which can be empty).

Try: `window.MQTTClient.disconnect();`

e.g.

```js
function test() {
    console.log("foo1");
}

function test2() {
   console.log("foo2");
}

test; // This will not do anything
test2();  // Will log "foo2"
```

If this does not help please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (currently we cannot see what else is using `window.MQTTClient`).

Comment: Oh, man. Surely it cannot be this simple... I'll try right now.

Comment: It solved the problem although I don't understand how the messages kept arriving although I removed the script from the DOM (or I think I did anyway). @Brits: Thank you man! always good to have an extra pair of eyes! Have a nice evening!

Comment: Removing a reference in the DOM (or setting it to `null`) will not stop code execution (well it might if the running code itself is part of the DOM, I'm not really sure!, but this code is in the imported library so has not been removed).

Comment: I've now changed the code so it will not load the library if it finds the element id already exists. This seems to work fine. I've given up on trying to remove the code from memory after running.